# C++ template of a template class without typedefs, is it possible?

Tags: c++, templates, standards

As title says, is there any way to pull something like this up?:

```
std::set<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>> variable;
```

I know it is against some version of the standard, but can it be avoided?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Your code works fine as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually should put a space between the two `>` characters:

```
std::set<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> > variable;
```

and of course `MyClass` should have been declared before you code the above.

The newest *C++11* standard removed the need to put a space between the `>` occurrences.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote "usually".

Comment: but is the c++11 standard completely implemented or atleast this part in all c++ compliers???

Comment: It depends on the version of the compiler. with GCC 4.6 when invoked as `g++-4.6 -std=c++0x` you can avoid the space between `>`

Answer (score 0):

in older standard >> is taken as input operator i suppose, irrelevant of where its used.

Comment: `>>` is actually a right shifting operator. Overloaded by iostream. (Not that it is very important though).